# Xamarin on Visual Studio for Mac - Cannot load storyboards

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have been learning Xamarin and am now starting with Xamarin Classic. I'm using a late 2014 Mac mini that is pretty slow. I've installed Xcode and Visual Studio, but when I try and open any .storyboard file, the wheel spins for a while and then a MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException is thrown. It is responding to a CoreSimulator.SimError code 165: Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted

I have the most recent version of Visual Studio installed, and Xcode 11.4. I have tried running sudo `xcrun simctl shutdown all` both before loading the Main.storyboard file and also while the file is loading (which was a recommended fix on StackOverflow), but neither of these worked.

I'm baffled as to what is causing this error. While I've managed to find information about the MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException error and the CoreSimulator.SimError, I have not been able to find both of them together.

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this to happen. I've tried downgrading to Mojave but that didn't work as Xcode 11.4 was needed for VS and that requires Catalina.

Here is the (truncated) error message from Visual Studio.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x00024] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:312 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:337 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession () [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:496 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:466 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1[TResult].<EnsureSession>b__1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00012] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:2072 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:202 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2759 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2625 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<>c__DisplayClass289_0`1[TResult].<EnsureSession>b__0 () [0x003b7] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:2146 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---


  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry (System.Xml.Linq.XElement storyboardClone, System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] optimisedReloadClones, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00091] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:750 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry (System.Xml.Linq.XElement storyboardClone, System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] optimisedReloadClones, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0022b] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:757 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.RenderXml (System.Xml.Linq.XElement storyboardClone, System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] optimisedReloadClones, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0004d] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:735 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.RenderXml (System.Xml.Linq.XElement storyboardClone, System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] optimisedReloadClones, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001a6] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:743 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.ReloadItemsAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] elements, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x002b4] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:624 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Tasks.Cancellable (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00024] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/TaskExtensions.cs:28 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.ReloadItems (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] elements) [0x00082] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:576 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x00024] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:312 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:337 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession () [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2029 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:496 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:466 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1[TResult].<EnsureSession>b__1 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00012] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:2072 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:202 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x00024] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:312 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:337 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession () [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 <---
<---




Contents of /Users/michael/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/8.0/iOSDesigner.2020-04-26__18-16-31.log:
Commit: 35aa4889dab48fb3471f20131d6f68dae41bc11c


[2020-04-26 18:18:32.6] INFO: IPhoneDesignerSdkManager: Initializing the designer service
[2020-04-26 18:18:33.1] INFO: ENTERING sandbox: AndroidDesignerMac


[2020-04-26 18:18:33.2] INFO: LEAVING sandbox: AndroidDesignerMac


[2020-04-26 18:19:26.0] INFO: Starting full reload...
[2020-04-26 18:20:07.0] INFO: Beginning the boostrap process for 843A9789-4EBB-4BAD-81FA-E6F24A2DFAE3 (iPad mini 4, iOS SDK 13.4 at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot)


[2020-04-26 18:20:07.1] PERF:    - Waited 29ms to clean up


[2020-04-26 18:20:07.1] PERF:    - Waited 2ms for device to finish creating


[2020-04-26 18:20:20.3] PERF:    - Booting time: 13192ms


[2020-04-26 18:20:29.4] WARN: Framebuffer unavailable; Xcode 10+ requires Library.Disposition.Local


[2020-04-26 18:20:29.5] PERF:    - Registering services: 9143ms


[2020-04-26 18:20:46.0] ERROR: Could not find SimulatorBridge after spawning it... bailing out.


[2020-04-26 18:20:46.3] ERROR: Service port lookup had failed with: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff40186b550 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"}}


[2020-04-26 18:20:47.4] INFO: An unexpected error happened trying to start the designer. Attempting to erase our device.
System.InvalidOperationException: Simulator services were not available after booting the simulator. Perhaps it has crashed.
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.LookupServices () [0x000bb] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.Start () [0x003c8] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c7] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:303 
[2020-04-26 18:20:47.4] ERROR: An exception occurred while launching, forcibly restarting the session.
[2020-04-26 18:20:50.7] PERF: Total time for shutting down: 3284ms


[2020-04-26 18:21:39.7] INFO: Successfully killed the entire session
[2020-04-26 18:25:07.2] INFO: Starting full reload...
[2020-04-26 18:25:07.3] INFO: Beginning the boostrap process for 843A9789-4EBB-4BAD-81FA-E6F24A2DFAE3 (iPad mini 4, iOS SDK 13.4 at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot)


[2020-04-26 18:25:07.3] PERF:    - Waited 1ms to clean up


[2020-04-26 18:25:07.3] PERF:    - Waited 2ms for device to finish creating


[2020-04-26 18:25:08.2] PERF:    - Booting time: 856ms


[2020-04-26 18:25:08.2] WARN: Framebuffer unavailable; Xcode 10+ requires Library.Disposition.Local


[2020-04-26 18:25:08.2] PERF:    - Registering services: 10ms


[2020-04-26 18:25:20.2] ERROR: Could not find SimulatorBridge after spawning it... bailing out.


[2020-04-26 18:25:20.2] ERROR: Service port lookup had failed with: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff40186d280 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"}}


[2020-04-26 18:25:20.2] INFO: An unexpected error happened trying to start the designer. Attempting to erase our device.
System.InvalidOperationException: Simulator services were not available after booting the simulator. Perhaps it has crashed.
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.LookupServices () [0x000bb] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.Start () [0x003c8] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c7] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:303 
[2020-04-26 18:25:20.2] ERROR: An exception occurred while launching, forcibly restarting the session.
[2020-04-26 18:25:24.2] PERF: Total time for shutting down: 3943ms


[2020-04-26 18:25:26.3] INFO: Successfully killed the entire session
[2020-04-26 18:25:26.4] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 1): System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.)) (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x00024] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:312 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:337 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession () [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x00024] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:312 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x001e8] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:337 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00057] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:282 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:252 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession () [0x00001] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:111 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0 () [0x00000] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:116 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:534 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 <---


[2020-04-26 18:25:26.5] INFO: Beginning the boostrap process for 843A9789-4EBB-4BAD-81FA-E6F24A2DFAE3 (iPad mini 4, iOS SDK 13.4 at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot)
[2020-04-26 18:25:27.0] WARN: Framebuffer unavailable; Xcode 10+ requires Library.Disposition.Local
[2020-04-26 18:25:38.1] ERROR: Could not find SimulatorBridge after spawning it... bailing out.


[2020-04-26 18:25:38.1] ERROR: Service port lookup had failed with: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge.1857: 0x3, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff401acaad0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"}}


[2020-04-26 18:25:38.1] INFO: An unexpected error happened trying to start the designer. Attempting to erase our device.
System.InvalidOperationException: Simulator services were not available after booting the simulator. Perhaps it has crashed.
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.LookupServices () [0x000bb] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Hosting.FullSession.Start () [0x003c8] in <34aca1c84ddb47319197d8fcd6d9539e>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c7] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:303
```

Comment: You can open the storyboard file use Visual studio and if you right click on the story board file in your solution explorer “using XCode interface builder”. Have you tried both options? Also what file are you trying to open-is it a new solution template, or an existing project?

Comment: Yeah, I've used Xcode Interface Builder, but it's a pain because I have to add the outlets manually in both the Main.storyboard file and the ViewController.designer.cs file before I can use them in the ViewController.cs file.

It would be nice to be able to use the VS iOS Designer which does all of the above for you. The file I'm trying to open is a new solution template.

Comment: Did you follow all these steps while connecting your computer to the Mac? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/ Also do you have the latest updates installed?